# Copy To clipboard in java after deploying war file into tomcat?

Tags: java, awt

`Toolkit.getdefaulttoolkit().getsystemclipboard().setcontents()` works fine when we run the application from eclipse. But after deploying the war file into tomcat it does not works as expected. Can any one give the solution?

Comment: Probably it works - but only on the machine where tomcat is running. A java application running as `war` package has only access to the servers resources, never to resources on client machines. These resources include the system clipboard.